# How to redirect traffic hosted on an azure endpoint (DNS/static IP) to different external IP address

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-traffic-manager, azure-load-balancer, azure-front-door

Question: How do I host an endpoint in azure which allows me to redirect internet traffic at will between azure and aws services?

I am hosting two kubernetes clusters - one in Azure and the other in AWS. I want to be able to: 
1.  redirect the traffic at will to either aws or azure, whilst retaining the public dns endpoint.
2.  fail over manually [and pref automatically too] to the aws cluster.  What is the best way to host the endpoint **in azure**?

Requirements:

- The traffic needs to be redirected immediately - no caching issues and stale loads!
- Ability to configure failover - i.e. specify that Azure is hot and AWS is the failover service - the traffic should be automatically redirected as soon as Azure goes down.

I have looked at Traffic Manager, Load Balancers and Application Gateway.  Not sure which one (if any) of these is best.

Comment: You can configure external endpoint in azure traffic manager and redirect traffic to aws cluster when the health probe of azure end point fails. For each end point a health probe will have to be configured in ATF. You will use priority routing mechanism wherein all traffic will go to azure endpoint and on failure of which it will be routed to aws endpoint. also u need to manage state across both or have a pure stateless system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

traffic manager wont work for you, since its a dns service, so caching will happen (admittedly its the best solution if you set dns cache to 5 seconds or something). application gateway allows you to specify an ip address as an endpoint, load balancers only work when attached to vms inside azure. But application gateways dont allow to failover at will. you would need to block the probe to failover.

Azure Front Door might be the solution for you (like the other answer mentions)

Comment: Thanks to both 4c74 and sasikant.  4c74 provides the fullest answer. I will check out Azure Front Door.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look into Azure Front Door Service for your usecase.

Look into this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/frontdoor/front-door-overview